# MPI error with matrix: segmentation fault

Tags: c, mpi

A program was written to find the minimum value in the matrix. At small values of the matrix dimension, it works correctly, however, if the dimension exceeds 350x350, then when calculating on a different number of nodes, a similar error occurs.

> mpirun noticed that process rank 4 with PID 15014 on node cluster exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).

Everything works on two cores, but not always on others.

I use the following commands:

> mpicc Lab777.c -o 1 -lm -std=c99
>
> mpirun -np 16 ./1

The code:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <time.h>

#define ROWS 350
#define COLS 350
#define max 999999999

void rand_matrix(int array[ROWS][COLS])
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            array[i][j] = rand();
}

void show(int array[ROWS][COLS])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            printf("\t|%d|", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void convert(int array[ROWS][COLS], int *conv_arr)
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            conv_arr[k] = array[i][j];
            k++;
        }
}

int find_min(int *array, int piece, int num_of_pieces)
{
    int result = max;
    for (int i = 0; i < (ROWS * COLS / (num_of_pieces)); i++)
        if (array[i] < result)
            result = array[i];
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int matrix[ROWS][COLS], lin_arr[ROWS * COLS], min;
    double startwtime, endwtime;

    int ProcNum;
    int ProcRank;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ProcNum);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ProcRank);
    int recv_matrix[ProcNum][ROWS * COLS], func[ProcNum];

    if (ProcRank == 0)
    {
        printf("Matrix is filling\n");
        rand_matrix(matrix);
        convert(matrix, lin_arr);
        printf("Matrix:\n");
        //show(matrix);

    }
    startwtime = MPI_Wtime(); 
    MPI_Scatter(&lin_arr[(ProcRank) * (ROWS * COLS / (ProcNum))], (ROWS * COLS / (ProcNum)), MPI_INT, &recv_matrix[ProcRank],(ROWS * COLS / (ProcNum)), MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    func[ProcRank] = find_min(recv_matrix[ProcRank], ProcRank, ProcNum);
    MPI_Reduce(&func[ProcRank], &min, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MIN, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    endwtime = MPI_Wtime();
    if (ProcRank == 0)
    {
        printf("Min value: %d\n", min);
        printf("Time: %.4f\n", endwtime-startwtime);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

UPD:

Trying to reduce memory for `recv_matrix` and `func`.
I added the following line :

```
#define MAXPROC 20
```

And changed the following:

```c
int recv_matrix[MAXPROC][ROWS * COLS], func[MAXPROC];
```

But now it works with a smaller matrix size

Comment: FWIW, In MPI, each task has its own address space (e.g. memory is local to each task), so you can reduce the memory footprint of `recv_matrix` and `func`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, I tried to reduce the memory, but then the dimension at which the program works even less: 308x308.

Comment: please update your code then. at first, you should keep it simple and only consider `(ROWS*COLS)%ProcNum == 0`

Comment: I don’t understand how to use it.

Comment: Why is `func` an array?

Comment: Oh, you noticed correct, my mistake, but it still doesn't work, even if remove it

Comment: What about `recv_matrix`, isn’t it way too big as well?

Comment: Hmmm, what do you mean? Use the line you wrote above? At the same time, the dimension increases slightly, but only works on 2 cores

Comment: I'm out of ideas

Comment: you are only using a fraction of `recv_matrix` and `func`, so you can reduce their size to the bare minimum. your code will become more efficient, cleaner and hence less error prone.

Comment: I understand this, but I do not understand what size these functions should have

Comment: how many elements do you use in `func` and in `recv_matrix` ?

Comment: In `recv_matrix` `ROWS * COLS / (ProcNum)`, in `func` `ROWS * COLS / (num_of_pieces)`, right? Sorry, the head no longer understands

Comment: `recv_matrix` is right, `func` is not.

Comment: Hmmm, It turns out that the function `recv_matrix` has `int recv_matrix[ProcNum][ROWS * COLS/(ProcNum)]` and it improves performance, but I can’t guess the size of the func

Comment: My advice is to write simple code that works first, and then only optimize if you need it.

Comment: I understand you well, but I would like to learn from you how I can solve this problem, to study what I did wrong and why.
It's easier for me to understand, learn from mistakes

Comment: I learnt a lot from my mistakes, well, only the one I fixed myself. Good speed!